# How prevent a model data save using _save_before event

Tags: module, magento-1, event-observer, model

I have create a model which has its own database table. For a customization I need to trigger `save_before` event of this model.

If one field value is not matched, then the data should not be saved.

**My main target is preventing data save using "before save" event**

#### My config.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custommodule>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>custommodule_resource</resourceModel>
            </custommodule>
            <custommodule_resource>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <custommodule>
                        <table>custommodule</table>
                    </custommodule>
                </entities>
            </custommodule_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <custommodule_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Amit_Custommodule</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </custommodule_setup>
            <custommoule_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </custommoule_read>
            <custommodule_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </custommodule_write>
        </resources>
        <events>
            <custommodule_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <custommodule>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                        <method>customerSaveAfter</method>
                    </custommodule>
                </observers>
            </custommodule_save_before>
    </global>


</config>
```

#### Observer.php

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Observer
{
public function customerSaveAfter($observer){

if($observer->getEvent()->getMyfield()==MatchWithMyLogic){
}
else
{
/*  i want prevent data base if my business logic is not match here */
}


}
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have a look at the method `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::save`, you see this code block:

```
try {
    $this->_beforeSave();
    if ($this->_dataSaveAllowed) {
        $this->_getResource()->save($this);
        $this->_afterSave();
    }
    $this->_getResource()->addCommitCallback(array($this, 'afterCommitCallback'))
        ->commit();
    $this->_hasDataChanges = false;
    $dataCommited = true;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->_getResource()->rollBack();
    $this->_hasDataChanges = true;
    throw $e;
}
```

In the `_beforeSave()` method in the second line, the `save_before` event is dispatched. Hence, you should be able to just throw an exception in your observer code. This should be catched by the try-catch-block above and should prevent the model to save.

Another possibility is the `_dataSaveAllowed` field. You can set it to false in your observer code. This will prevent the model to save. And this field is exactly designed for this purpose as the PHP doc reveals:

```
/**
 * Flag which can stop data saving after before save
 * Can be used for next sequence: we check data in _beforeSave, if data are
 * not valid - we can set this flag to false value and save process will be stopped
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_dataSaveAllowed = true;
```

Comment: simon,can you please check p@programmer_rkt answer,is good logic?

Comment: @AmitBera Feels a bit hacky what he does and I do not really get the point... See my comment.

Comment: @Simon : check those comments please. Its just a logic. I didn't try that before.

Comment: dear simmon,if i add protected $_dataSaveAllowed = false add in myobsever then is should work?

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that the field is `protected`. I thought that you can do something like `$observer->getDataObject()->setDataSaveAllowed(false)`, but there is no respective setter. Hence, you can only use this approach with a custom model where you can add a setter for the field. For Magento or other models you do not control, use the exception approach.

Comment: Even if it wasn't protected, you couldn't do this since almost all objects are passed by value not by reference. I think this should be bold noted.

Comment: Note - make sure your observer method doesn't have a try-catch, otherwise the exception won't bubble up to `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::save`! Seems obvious yes, but easy to overlook and waste time on.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to prevent the save method to execute for a core model (i.e. Catalog/Product), you can use reflection to set "$_dataSaveAllowed" to false:

```
public function catalogProductSaveBefore($observer)
{
    try {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('Mage_Catalog_Model_Product');
        $reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('_dataSaveAllowed');
        $reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
        $reflectionProperty->setValue($product, false);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try @Simon answer first. But if you need to still go for save in both condition, then you can use this cocept

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerSaveAfter($observer)
    {

        if ($observer->getEvent()->getMyfield() == MatchWithMyLogic) {
            //do some other works
            //save data normally
        } else {
            //defines your modules model
            $model = Mage::getModel('model_alias/entity');
            //get entity id that is trying to save if any
            $id = (int)$observer->getEvent()->getEntityId();
            if ($id >= 0 ) {
                //load the correspondign model and retrieve data
                $data = $model->load($id)->getData();

                //set this value to the current object that is trying to save
                $observer->getEvent()->setData($data); 
            } else {
                //set null value for all fields for new entity
                $observer->getEvent()->setData(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What this method does is, it will first collect data that is correspond to the entity that is going to save and then set current data with that value. This results into save the previous value itself into the database. If there is no entity id present, that means its a new entity. So save null  values for that field

### EDIT

My friends Simon and AmitBera got confused on this part

```
else {
        //set null value for all fields for new entity
        $observer->getEvent()->setData(null);
}
```

So it would be good to explain this part little bit. Suppose the table has two fiels `field_one` and `field_two`. In that case, for a new entity (means this has no entry in database), we can set those values like this.

```
 $observer->getEvent()->setEntityOne('');
  $observer->getEvent()->setEntityTwo('');
```

This will erase the value that passed and set null value. So during save action, this empty values will be stored in database.

Take idea that I am trying to convey and please don't judge on the basis of demo code that I have provided :)

Comment: Could you explain it a bit further? I do not really get the point. The base idea is that when you set the data to null, nothing will be saved?

Comment: this is `before_save` action. Means `save` and `aftersave` actions has to take place. So edited entity may be already existing one in database or a new one. If edited entity has an entry in database, we will get that values and set those values instead of changed values that are currently hold by the entity/object. so when save action takes place, the value set now is previous value itself. This makes no table value updation. Means previous values get saved.

Comment: for new entities, means those has no entry in database, instead of using initial values that are currently hold by that entity, we set null values. This will make a new entry in database with all field has null value in it. if `setData(null)` didnt work, I guess `setData(array())` may work (null array). Its just a logic

Comment: @Simon : did you get my point ?

Comment: but it may create issue on exiting records which  set field value to be null

Comment: @Simon : My method not stops save processing. Save process will happen. But the data that is going to update during save action will be the previous data itself

Comment: Yes, I did, thanks. Feels a bit hacky. And it may save a dummy entity which is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: that is not good ideas.

Comment: @AmitBera : That is upto you friend. You only know what are the fields. I just gave you an idea. Not a full solution. The logic is correct I think. But I still recommend Simon method.

Comment: @Simon : I didn't get "that is not the desired behaviour". Can you elaborate it more ? I am sorry. I may be wrong. But logic is correct as per me... and it should work. :)

Comment: @programmer_rkt I am actually not sure on that one, but if you set the data to null Magento may save an entity containing null values, no? This would indeed be bad.

Comment: again again I am telling you this is a concept, a logic. I know AmitBera is talented enough. I just tried him to give that idea. But for the sake for future visitors I put that code there. So please dont judge my code :). Try to grasp the idea that i am trying to convey

Comment: @Simon : Uff.. you are telling me about setting null value for new entity right. May be its wrong in code. But what about already existing entity ? Is that correct approach ?

Comment: I have edited my answer please go through it

Comment: @Simon : See my edit

Comment: @programmer_rkt yeah, that is alright. Just wanted to mention the problems that may occur with this solution. You should test it anyway - no matter which approach you take :)

Comment: @Simon : I think now you got my idea. thanks for your time. and for that superb answer. I posted this answer, if in case amit has to go for saveaction instead of stop save action, he can use my idea

Comment: @RajeevKTomy Could you pls help me with observer error https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284557/57334

Answer (score 0):

**This may affect more than just the customer object you're trying to prevent from saving**, but you can do this in your observer to prevent the save from being applied in the database.

```
$customer->getResource()->rollBack();
Mage::throwException('Invalid customer account information');
```

The thrown exception alone won't do it, so you must attempt to rollback the transaction with InnoDB. However, there might be more than just this customer account being modified/created in that transaction, so use this with caution.