# Cancel save() in custom model if condition is met in _beforeSave()

Tags: module, event-observer, model, magento-1, validation

I have a custom model and I want to add a validation in the `_beforeSave()` method so that if it's a new object, and no `customer_id` has been set, it shouldn't save the record at all. I did the validations on my pages but that doesn't keep other developers from doing something like:

```
$myModel = Mage::getModel("myModule/myModel");
$myModel->save();
```

This shouldn't happen because some values **must** be set before saving. I want something like:

```
public function _beforeSave()
{
    parent::_beforeSave();
    if($this->getCustomerId() <= 0)
    {
         #cancel save
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Can I cancel the save() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi need to throw a magento exception when match you logic

or set variable `$_dataSaveAllowed=true`

and
set if false `when  before logic is match with cancel condition`

```
$this->_dataSaveAllowed=false;
```

and note that you need  `call parent::_beforesave()` after condition check

```
protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        $this->_dataSaveAllowed = true;

    if($this->getCustomerId() <= 0)
        {
         #cancel save
          $this->_dataSaveAllowed = false;
        }

    return parent::_beforeSave();
    }
```

Just like

```
 throw Mage::exception(
                'Mage_Customer', Mage::helper('customer')->__('This customer email already exists'),
                Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS
            );
```

See some brief description

[How prevent a model data save using _save_before event](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34336/how-prevent-a-model-data-save-using-save-before-event)

Comment: Hey, thanks man. I thought about throwing an exception but I went with `$_dataSaveAllowed=false`. This model isn't exactly an important one and I did not want to throw a nasty exception. You can go ahead and mark this question as a duplicate though, I did not find yours first.