# How to stop saving resource model and throw error messages inside _beforeSave function?

Tags: magento-2.1, resource-model, interceptor

I have the following codes inside a custom resourceModel class:

```
protected function _beforeSave(
    AbstractModel $object
)
{
    //My operations
    return parent::_beforeSave($object);
}
```

I added a checking inside `_beforeSave()` but I don't know how to prevent the resuorce model to continue the save actions.

I found this answer but it's for M1. I need a M2 solution.

[Cancel save() in custom model if condition is met in _beforeSave()](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37934/cancel-save-in-custom-model-if-condition-is-met-in-beforesave)

Comment: You can do the same in M2 just set                 `$this->_dataSaveAllowed = false;` if your condition does not satisy

Comment: Not working, the save action continue in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just throw exception.

```
protected function _beforeSave(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
    {

     if(!$object->getData('identifier')):
         throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('The page URL key not set.')
            );
     endif;
        return parent::_beforeSave($object);

}
```

Comment: My bad. Actually I want sth like `Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface::addErrorMessage(__('The page URL key not set.'));`. Your method will throw an error page like PHP error.

Comment: @PYYick this is used magento 2  default ResourceModel you can check it `Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block.php`

Comment: I don't know why in my case, when throw exceptions, will generate a page like PHP syntax error. While in Magento_Cms it shows error message like the one I want.